# Can't close after awk command inside for loop to read and write multiple files

Tags: bash, csv, awk

I have a set of csv files, one of them has a timestamp, all the other ones just have data, but they all have the same number of rows.  The timestamp is in the 2nd column of the csv.

I would like to append the timestamp to the first column of all csv files.  This is currently working but when I try to close the files, I get an error.  There can be 50-500 csv files, and each can have thousands of rows, so that is why I wonder if the close() is required.

Also, can anyone suggest any ways of improving this script either for performance or for reliability and check for any errors?

Sample input
blah_blah_blah_timestamp.csv

```
name, time
1,121
2,122
3,123
```

data1.csv

```
name,X1
A1,11
A2,12
A3,15
```

data2.csv

```
name,Y1,Y2,Y3
B1,1,1,2
B2,2,1,3
B3,3,2,4
```

data3.csv

```
name,Z1,Z2,Z3
C1,1,9,5
C2,2,8,4
C3,3,7,3
```

out/data1.csv

```
time,name,X1
121,A1,11
122,A2,12
123,A3,15
```

out/data2.csv

```
time,name,Y1,Y2,Y3
121,B1,1,1,2
122,B2,2,1,3
123,B3,3,2,4
```

out/data3.csv

```
time,name,Z1,Z2,Z3
121,C1,1,9,5
122,C2,2,8,4
123,C3,3,7,3
```

current script

```
#!/bin/bash
mkdir -p out
ts='blah_blah_blah_timestamp.csv'
for sfile in *.csv;
do
   awk -F, -v afile="$sfile" '{getline f1 < afile ;print $2, f1}' OFS=, $ts >  out/"$sfile"
   close('sfile')
done
```

Comment: `close` is an awk function. You can't use it outside your awk script.

Comment: Awk will close the file for you. You can use awk to loop over files.

Comment: @Ed Morton, I have added the same input and expected output.  From reading the above comments, looks like close() is not required.  I just want to make sure that this wont cause problems with a large set of data, and wonder if there are better ways to do this.

Comment: No, `close()` **is** required if you aren't using gawk (and if you are it's highly desirable). Without it you **willl** have problems with large data sets. I'll take a look at the question now you've provided a full [mcve], thanks for doing that.

Comment: @EdMorton Ok thank you for clarifying that it is required.  The script "working" without the close() but I didn't want it to fail with much larger data sets.  Currently was only testing with 100 csvs.

Comment: Let me clarify - what you had, a shell loop calling awk once per input file, didn't need a `close()`, it's just when you do it the right way and only call awk once for all input files with no surrounding shell loop that you need to close() each output file as you go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably what you want:

```
awk '
BEGIN { FS=OFS="," }
NR==FNR {
    map[FNR] = $2
    next
}
FNR==1 {
    close(out)
    out = "out/" FILENAME
}
{ print map[FNR], $0 > out }
' blah_blah_blah_timestamp.csv data*.csv
```

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/65814521/1745001 for an explanation for why/how I'm using `close()`.

By the way, if you're ever considering using `getline` in future - it's rarely the right approach and it's hard to use correctly, see http://awk.freeshell.org/AllAboutGetline.