# AWK - syntax error: unexpected end of file

Tags: linux, bash, awk

I have about 300 files in a folder, trying to remove comma in CSV, when I run in the loop I got an error

MY CODE :

```
#!/bin/bash
FILES=/home/whoisdat/all-data/*
{

for f in $FILES
do  

{
awk -F'"' -v OFS='' '{ for (i=2; i<=NF; i+=2) gsub(",", "", $i) } 1' $f > allan-$f
}
done
```

Error:

```
root@s1.allheartweb.com [all-data]# sh /home/all-data/unique.sh
/home/whoisdat/all-data/unique.sh: line 12: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

Comment: You  don't need to loop on the files, just do awk '{....}' /home/whoisdat/all-data/*

Comment: @Raman 

awk -F'"' -v OFS='' '{ for (i=2; i<=NF; i+=2) gsub(",", "", $i) } 1' *  > allan-* 

THis ?

Comment: What's to do with your braces? They're completely redundant. The error is exactly because you missed a `}` at the end.

Comment: copy/paste your script into http://shellcheck.net and fix the issues it tells you about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The right way to do what you're doing is:

```
awk -F'"' -v OFS='' '
    FNR==1 { close(out); out="allan-"FILENAME }
    { for (i=2; i<=NF; i+=2) gsub(/,/, "", $i); print > out }
' /home/whoisdat/all-data/*
```

We close the previous output file when we start reading the next input file to avoid a "too many open files" error from most awks when we get past a limit of a dozen or so (GNU awk which can handle many open files suffers a slowdown instead which is also undesirable), and we only close it there instead of once per input line processed to avoid the significant performance hit of opening and closing output files once per input line.

The above assumes you aren't running the command under /home/whoisdat/all-data/ and so creating allan-* files in /home/whoisdat/all-data/ while the script is running.

Answer (score 1):

```
awk -F'"' -v OFS='' '{ for (i=2; i<=NF; i+=2) gsub(",", "", $i);print $0 >> ("allan-"FILENAME);close("allan-"FILENAME) }' /home/whoisdat/all-data/*
```

There is no need to loop on the files, just allow awk to process all the files and use FILENAME to track the files being processed.