# Should I replace cat, sed and sort commands to collate multiple csv files by timestamp in script that also uses awk?

Tags: bash, csv, sorting, awk, sed

1. I want to collate a large set of csv files based on a timestamp that is in the first column of each source csv file (ts.csv, x.csv, y.csv and z.csv in this example).  All csv files have the same number of rows.
2. Before the csv are collated, when they are written out to the collated.csv I want each row to have some additional information at the front: row number, FILENAME without .csv, timestamp.
3. Timestamp should come from the 2nd column of the ts.csv file (each row has a different timestamp).  To clarify ts.csv has 2 timestamps, the first column has the timestamp that is used to collate all files, and the 2nd column has the timestamp that is added to all other files.  This 3rd part is already resolved thanks to Ed Norton in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65795640/cant-close-after-awk-command-inside-for-loop-to-read-and-write-multiple-files)

For the other parts I've modified his script slightly to print additional fields and also added this other line to my bash script

```
cat out/*.csv | sed s/.csv// | sort -t, -nk4 > out/collated.csv
```

this is the full script:

```
!/bin/bash
rm out/*      
mkdir -p out  
awk '
BEGIN { FS=OFS="," }
NR==FNR {
    map[FNR] = $2
    next
}
FNR==1 {
    close(out)
    out = "out/" FILENAME
}
{ print FNR, FILENAME, map[FNR], $0 > out }
' ts.csv *.csv

cat out/*.csv | sed s/.csv// | sort -t, -nk4 > out/collated.csv
```

Is there a better way to do what the cat, sed and sort commands are doing? maybe as part of the awk?  Since I can have 50-500 csv files and each can have tens of thousands of rows, I worry about future performance. I am wondering whats a better way to do this?

Also, how can I get rid of the first 4 lines in the output file which only contain the headers since they are basically th same as the filename.

These are my sample input files:

`````
```
$ cat x.csv
time,x
1.1,7.6
2.12,7.5
3.1,7.1
$ cat y.csv
time,y1,y2,y3
1.11,1,1,1
2.22,2,2,2
3.23,3,3,3
$ cat z.csv
time,z1,z2
1.03,1,4
2.41,2,5
3.13,3,6
$ cat ts.csv 
time,t1
1.11,4.7
2.21,5.8
3.31,6.2
````
`````

And my current output:

```
cat out/collated.csv 
1,ts,t1,time,t1
1,x,t1,time,x
1,y,t1,time,y1,y2,y3
1,z,t1,time,z1,z2
2,z,4.7,1.03,1,4
2,x,4.7,1.1,7.6
2,ts,4.7,1.11,4.7
2,y,4.7,1.11,1,1,1
3,x,5.8,2.12,7.5
3,ts,5.8,2.21,5.8
3,y,5.8,2.22,2,2,2
3,z,5.8,2.41,2,5
4,x,6.2,3.1,7.1
4,z,6.2,3.13,3,6
4,y,6.2,3.23,3,3,3
4,ts,6.2,3.31,6.2
```

**Update:**
This is the updated script after Raman's suggestion:

```
!/bin/bash
rm out2/*.csv
mkdir -p out2
awk '
BEGIN { FS=OFS="," }
NR==FNR {
    map[FNR] = $2
    next
}
FNR==1 {
    close(out)
    out = "out2/" FILENAME
}
{ print map[FNR], $0 > out }
' ts.csv *.csv

awk -F, '
BEGIN { cnt++ } # counter for row number in original csv, skip 1 for header 
FNR != 1 { # Skip the headers
   map[$1][$0]=FILENAME # Create 2 dimensional array with the timestamp as the first index and the line the second. 
                       #The file name is the value
} 
END { 
   PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@ind_str_asc"; # At the end of processing the files, set the array ordering.
   for (i in map) { 
      cnt++; # Increment the counter
      for (j in map[i]) { 
         split(map[i][j],map1,"[./]"); # Loop through the the array and strip the ".csv" out of the filenames
         print cnt","map1[2]","j # Print the data required
      } 
   } 
}' out2/*.csv > out2/collated.csv
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. When using grep, sed, awk, almost certainly the answer is "yes, you may not use cat". This is valid on a general note.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your output doesn't match your sample input but try the following (using GNU awk for array sorting):

```
awk -F, 'FNR != 1 { map[$1][$0]=FILENAME } END { PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@ind_str_asc";for (i in map) { cnt++;for (j in map[i]) { split(map[i][j],map1,".");print cnt","map1[1]","j } } }' *.csv > out/collated.csv
```

Explanation:

```
awk -F, 'FNR != 1 { # Skip the headers
                    map[$1][$0]=FILENAME # Create 2 dimensional array with the timestamp as the first index and the  line the second. The file name is the value
                  } 
              END { 
                    PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@ind_str_asc"; # At the end of processing the files, set the array ordering.
                    for (i in map) { 
                        cnt++; # Increment a counter
                        for (j in map[i]) { 
                          split(map[i][j],map1,"."); # Loop through the the array and strip the ".csv" out of the filenames
                          print cnt","map1[1]","j # Print the data required
                        } 
                     } 
                   }' *.csv > out/collated.csv
```

Comment: @ Raman thank you for the help.  This mostly worked, I added BEGIN { cnt++ } so it would skip one for the headers that are stripped and I start at 2.  and also changed the split to split(map[i][j],map1,"[./]"); since it was printing "out/" in front of the file name, and changed the map1[1] to map1[2] in the print line.

Comment: Great! If it has helped you reach your objective, please up vote and accept the solution.

Comment: quick question on the sorting, it seems it currently is sorting on the timestamp that is in the first column from first step, which after cnt and map1[1] gets added is the 3rd column out collated.csv.  What if I wanted to sort it on based on the 4th column overall ? and is there a way to specify a 2nd sorting method if the first is the same?

Comment: You would need to change the indexing of the array.